# How to pass parameter in url action while calling .load function in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below piece of code
But Its giving error param1 doesnot exist  in current context

```
   $('#dialog').dialog({

                autoOpen: true,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'My Table',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                 var param1 = $('#txtfirst').val();
                 var param2 = $('#txtlast').val();
                url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("Index1", new { first = param1, last = param2 })))";
                alert(url);
                 $(this).load(url);
///////////////////////////
<div id="dialog"></div> 
<input id="txtfirst" type="text"/>
<input id="txtlast" type="text"/>      
<input type="button" value="Get Form" onclick="getForm()" />
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question and format it properly.

Comment: check url=  line. you can't use double quotation twice. Try to use simple quot. inside

Comment: As the error said, you are using a helper in the server side context. What I mean is `param1` and `param2` will be interpreted as previously declared variables.